# How to get a equivalent localized string of a number ?

Tags: java, android, text, locale

I'm trying to convert numbers into a localized equivalent string (for an android app).

For example I would like to convert `25` into `twenty five` if the locale is `US`.

If the locale is `FR` I would like `237` to be converted into `deux cent trente sept`.

I searched a lot in the Android documentation without finding anything. ( [Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html), [TextUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html), ... )

I also looked around into other library such as Apache Commons [LocaleUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/LocaleUtils.html), without success.

I'm wondering if such a library even exists.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing up localization with *translation* here. Locales in Java are typically used for formatting.

You could have a look at [google-api-translate-java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/).